# Add custom culture to web service?

Tags: c#, web-services, date

I have a web service on a server for which i won't be able to manage regional settings. My web methods need a date format "d.M.YYYY", so when i make a call to a web method and pass date-time string, the server should parse this string into a date format "d.M.YYYY" only, with date separator "."
In my desktop application i am doing this with the following code:

```
 public partial class MainF : Form
 {
   CultureInfo customCulture = new CultureInfo(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

      public MainF()
      {
           InitializeComponent();

           customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "d.M.yyyy";
           customCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = ".";
           Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = customCulture;
      }
      private void DisplayDate(string date)
      {
        string output="";
        DateTime myDate;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(input, customCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Date cannot be parsed!");
        }
        else
        {
           MessageBox.Show(myDate.ToShortDateString());
        }
      }
 }
```

But in my webservice where should i put the definition for date format,date separator and current thread culture = custom culture??? In every single method or not? Sorry but i am not too familiar with web services by now. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanna supply *custom* format, you need to use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact) method instead of `DateTime.TryParse`. For example;

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(input, customCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern, 
                          customCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out myDate))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Date cannot be parsed!");
}
```

`Exact` is the difference between these two methods which points to custom format.

By the way, I don't see *any* `input` in your code as a variable maybe you might mixing it with `date` or `output` variables..

Comment: In fact my question was about web service part which is not posted here, the above is my desktop app code which is working perfectly. Yes, here i do not have the input for date because it is not interesting. But for example, the input string is date="03-12-2015 13:05:26" and if we assume that output =myDate.ToShortDateString(); then the result will be 3.12.2015

Comment: @user3312687 But in such a case, you _have to_ know which format data you get from this service since you don't get it as `DateTime`. Then you can parse this string with proper format and format it again to get  `3.12.2015` as a result.